# How to enclose the List items within double quotes in Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a String variable containing few column names separated by comma. For example :

> val temp = "Col2, Col3, Col4"

I have a Dataframe and I want to group the Dataframe based on certain columns which include the columns stored in temp variable as well. For example my groupBy statement should act like the following statement

> DF.groupBy("Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4")

The temp variable may have any column names. So i want to create a GroupBy statement that gets the value of temp variable dynamically along with manual entries provided by me.

I tried with the following statement but to no avail
DF.groupBy("Col1", temp)

Then I splitted the value of temp variable based on comma sign and stored them in another variable and tried to pass it to the groupBy statement. But even that fails.

> val temp1 = temp.split(",")
>
> DF.groupBy("Col1", temp1)

Any ideas how I can enclose the values of a List variable within double quotes and pass the same to a groupBy statement ?

Comment: `DF.groupBy("Col1", temp: _*)` This assumes that the `groupBy()` takes any number of `String` arguments via the standard varargs syntax.

Comment: Thanks @jwvh for your valuable input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use varargs:

```
df.groupBy("Col1", temp1: _*)
```

or

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

df.groupBy("Col1 +: temp1 map col: _*)
```

Comment: Thank you so much @user8371915 for your valuable inputs